# Powershell with Dataloop/Outlyer

Tags: powershell, nagios

I'm not sure if this is the correct page for this question but I'm having a hard time getting Dataloop to properly display a widget based on my Powershell script's exit code.

I've just began playing with Dataloop monitoring so I may be going about this all wrong, but as far as I can tell from their documentation, they use the same error code system as Nagios and that those error codes map to a .status metric within Dataloop which you can use for displaying widgets.

As a test, I created the following Powershell script:

```
if (Test-path c:\scripts02) {
    Write-Host "I found the directory!"
    exit 0
} 
else {
    Write-Host "I could not find the directory!"
    exit 2
}
```

When I run the plugin test through the Dataloop site, this prints out the "I could not find the directory!" message along with the correct exit code of 2. When I change the path it's testing to an existing directory, it does exit with 0 and the correct output message. Everything seems to work as expected before until I move to the next part.

Inside Dataloop, I'd attempt to add a widget, set the source to one of my agents, select the "status" metric for my test plugin (the powershell script). The widget just appears with a gray screen when it should be green since the directory path does exist...

Has anyone had success with this? I checked out their documentation and tried the steps outlined there but have had no success.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's interested, this is actually a bug in the dataloop agent v1.1. Updated to v1.3 and code executes properly and reports the correct exit code.

On a side note, I had to use the function below to get dataloop to report properly as well instead of the "exit [int]" in my original code above:

```
function ExitWithCode {
    param($exitcode)

    $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode)
    exit
}
```